# VSTS 2017 build fails to find Newtonsoft libraray

Tags: azure-pipelines

Solution structure:

Project01: Class Library
Target Framework .NET Standard 2.0
[image: Project01 Dependencies]

Project02:

- Target Framework 4.6.1
- Has reference to Project01
- Other references shown below
- Newtonsoft reference here is 11.0.2 targeting "net461"

[image: Project02 Dependencies]

The solution builds fine in VS 2017.

Tried creating a Build Definition in VSTS like this:

[image: Build Steps]

[image: Build Solution Steps]

The build fails to find Newtonsoft:

```
 Error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Newtonsoft' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

What can be done to fix this?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you build the project with local VS? How did you restore the packages for the projects?

Comment: Can you reproduce this issue with the new project? Can you share the build log here?